# Distinguish a user depending on which page he comes from. Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to know if there is a way to differentiate a user depending on which page he comes from.

In my template, I would like to display something only if the user comes from a specific view (I wan't to display the same page I display for the others users, but adding a popup telling him something).

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

- You can set a cookie in the first view, and check its value in the destination view. Don't forget to clean the cookie if the user goes through another page in between. Downside is that the user can disable cookies in his browser.
- Depending on the way the user goes to the destination view (a link or a form), you can use a GET or a POST parameter.
- Use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)

Answer (score 3):

If possible, use [HTTP_REFERER request header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META). This works in most cases. If it doesn't, then you'll have to maintain it in the session.

To know what view function would a URL call, use `django.core.urlresolvers.resolve`. I think this is not documented but it's pretty straight forward, example:

```
In [1]: from django.core import urlresolvers

In [2]: urlresolvers.resolve('/admin/')
Out[2]: ResolverMatch(func=<function index at 0xadb1924>, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name='index', app_name='admin', namespace='admin')

In [3]: urlresolvers.resolve('/admin/').func
Out[3]: <function django.contrib.admin.sites.index>
```

Now, using that against the HTTP_REFERER in a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) could look like this:

```
from django import template
from django.core import urlresolvers

from yourapp.views import specific_view

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def comes_from_specific_view(request):
    if not request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', None):
        return False

    return urlresolvers.resolve(request.META['HTTP_REFERER']).func == specific_view
```

In template:

```
{% if request|comes_from_specific_view %}show popup{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I finally used session. It was simpler for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward general way I can think of is making a middleware class that saves the previous request path in the user session and then using `{{ user.session.previous_page }}` in the template. For example:

```
class ReferrerMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
       if request.user.is_authenticated():
           request.user.session['previous_page'] = request.session['current_page']
           request.user.session['current_page'] = request.path
```